# iPython uses wrong version of numPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 2.7.10 on my Mac OSX machine (Yosemite) and recently installed numpy using 'sudo pip install numpy' which I realise I probably shouldn't have now, but anyway since then I've been having issues with the versions of numpy that iPython thinks I'm using.

When I start iPython and import numpy, and print numpy.version.version, it says version 1.8.0rc1.

However when I try to do a:pip install numpy --upgrade it keeps saying it's the latest version.
pip freeze | grep numpy 
This gives me numpy 1.13.3.

Now when I try to run Jupyter Notebook, it uses the same numpy version as iPython and complains it needs a newer version.

What do I need to do?
I tried doing sudo easy_install numpy but it keeps saying it's the latest version.

Thanks for any help, sorry if this is a newbie question, tried searching for it but haven't come up with anything that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest version of numpy for Python 2.7

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: those are for windows

Comment: I have installed numpy 1.13. It is just in a different directory: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy. 
However there is another (original) version of numpy installed by Mac OSX at:
/Systems/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/ that it keeps reverting to whenever I enter ipython.

I can't seem to uninstall or upgrade that version, no matter what I do.

Comment: I resorted to renaming the older numpy directory to something else (numpyOld) to force python to use the new numpy library and that seems to have worked. Not the best way to do things, I imagine, but can someone explain to me how to properly upgrade numpy?